# Strange equation after derivative

Tags: derivatives, fourier-analysis

Assume Fourier integral of this function
$
f(x)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 , \left | x \right |< 1 & \\ 
0 , \left | x \right |> 1 & 
\end{matrix}\right. $ is this:

$$ f(x)= \frac{2}{\pi }\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{sin\omega}{\omega}cos\omega xd\omega  $$

Now calculate $$ \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{sin{x^2}}{x}dx $$

**Solution:**

Because $x=0$ is a continuous point then:

$$ 1=\frac{2}{\pi }\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{sin\omega }{\omega }cos(0)d\omega \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{sin\omega }{\omega }d\omega =\frac{\pi }{2} $$ $$(1)$$

Now lets to solve the integral. if we assume $ x^{2}=t $ then:

$$ x^{2}=t \Rightarrow 2xdx=dt \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{2t} ,\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=0 \Rightarrow t=0\\ x=\infty \Rightarrow t=\infty 
\end{matrix}\right.
 $$

And finally:

$$ I= \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{sint}{2t}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{sint}{t}dt \overset{(1)}{\rightarrow} I=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{\pi }{2}=\frac{\pi }{4} $$

**Question:**

How $2xdx=dt$ becomes $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{2t}$$ ?

Comment: Divide both sides by $2x^2$. Replace the $x^2$ on the right hand side by $t$.

Comment: $2xdx=dt\rightarrow\frac {2xdx}{2x^2}=\frac {dt}{2x^2}\rightarrow\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{2t}$ since $x^{2}=t$.

Comment: @KittyL Great! I got it. thanks

Comment: @Albert Thanks. should I close my question?

Comment: You can keep it for other peoples' reference.

Comment: @KittyL Please provide your reply as answer. because I want to choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide both sides by $2x^2$. Replace the $x^2$ on the right hand side by $t$.